# Materialize CSS transparent navbar

Tags: html, css, materialize

I have trouble making my navbar transparent. Instead what shows is a white background. I have even tried editing the materialize css source files and adding the class 'transparent' and nothing changes. Does anyone have a work around for this?

```
<div class="navbar-fixed transparent">
<nav class="transparent">
    <div class="nav-wrapper transparent">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">KAYWA</a>
        <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse" id="btncollapse">
            &#9776;
        </a>
        <ul class="left hide-on-med-and-down transparent">
            <li><a href="#" class="link">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link">CONTACT US</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down transparent">
            <li><a href="#" class="link"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">SOCIAL MEDIA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: try adding different background color for body and see if the navbar color changes

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple CSS solution that should work:

```
.transparentBG {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Then you put this class in the nav tag, after the div that makes navbar fixed, no need to replicate in your entire code.

Comment: Materialize already has a `transparent` class :) Still helped me find it, so thx!

Comment: When i was using, it didn't work, so i create this workaround... but later i found that i was missing params... haha

Comment: But the text color is white and making it transparent also make the text disappear

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background color of an element to transparent inherits the background color of the container which by default is white.

Answer (score 0):

```
.z-depth-1, 
nav, 
.card-panel, 
.card, 
.toast, 
.btn, 
.btn-large, 
.btn-small, 
.btn-floating, 
.dropdown-content, 
.collapsible, 
.sidenav {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

paste this in a css file and it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Name your nav class like this `N/A transparent`

example:

```
<div class="navbar-fixed">
    <nav class="N/A transparent ">
      <div >
        <a href="/" class="brand-logo"> Mywebsite</a>
          <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
          <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```